# Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.2.1@aar

Tags: firebase, android-studio

My app was working all of sudden this error popped up.

```
Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.2.1@aar.
Required by:
    project :app
Search in build.gradle files
```

tried importing the modules suggested by Android not working